# Python - Fuzz Testing

Tags: python, testing

I am making this Fuzz Testing in Python but I have some issues. When I compile this code I have the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "vm_main.py", line 33, in <module> 
    import main 
  File "/tmp/vmuser_tgqlkfrnov/main.py", line 44 
    return fuzzit 
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Can I have an advice?

This is my code:

```
import array

import random

import math

content = """
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Phasellus sollicitudin condimentum libero,
sit amet ultrices lacus faucibus nec.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras nulla nisi, accumsan gravida commodo et,
venenatis dignissim quam. Mauris rutrum ullamcorper consectetur.
Nunc luctus dui eu libero fringilla tempor. Integer vitae libero purus.
Fusce est dui, suscipit mollis pellentesque vel, cursus sed sapien.
Duis quam nibh, dictum ut dictum eget, ultrices in tortor.
In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi et leo enim.
Aenean ipsum ipsum, laoreet vel cursus a, tincidunt ultrices augue.
Aliquam ac erat eget nunc lacinia imperdiet vel id nulla."""


def fuzzit(content):

    buf = bytearray(content)
    strlst = list()

    for j in range(numwrites):
        rbyte = random.randrange(256)
        rn = random.randrange(len(buf))
        buf[rn] = "%c" %(rbyte)
        strlst[i] = array.tostring(buf)
fuzzed = strlst[:]
return fuzzit
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: If that's your code, as posted, then your indentations are off.. Indent the last 2 lines properly, to be part of the function and the syntax error will be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Python uses indent set it's structure instead of curly braces. You're `return` needs to be indented to align with your `for` statement.

From the looks of it, it looks like you are trying to return the `fuzzit` method in your .py ? This is not possible to do i python, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Now I have aligned with the for statement but when I run the code I have this error: Incorrect. There was a NameError. These errors arise for: Name not found globally

Comment: I have to write a random fuzzer, based on Charlie Miller's example
for a text viewer application.For multiple iterations, the procedure, fuzzit, should take in the content of a text file, pass the content into a byte array, randomly modify bytes of the "file", and add the resulting byte array (as a String) to a list. The return value of the fuzzit procedure should be a list of  byte-modified strings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you understood Fredrik concerning indenting.  It looks like your strlst is what you want to return.  Try this

```
for j in range(numwrites):
    rbyte = random.randrange(256)
    rn = random.randrange(len(buf))
    buf[rn] = "%c" %(rbyte)
    strlst[i] = array.tostring(buf)
return strlst[:]
```

Comment: Thank you for your hint but I have this error with your code: Incorrect. There was a NameError. These errors arise for: Name not found globally

Comment: You have strlst[i] but you don't have an i variable.  Should it be j?

Comment: You are right, but I have the same issue, I don't understand why I continue to have the same error

Comment: you don't declare buf in the function either.  Can you put up the exact traceback

Comment: They're telling me that the error is because I have not defined the numwrites. Someone could tell me how to do??